# Discrete value continuous scale, plotting multiple dataframes

Tags: r, ggplot2

Not long ago I had success plotting multiple dataframes, this time I have apparently done something different.

In summary, I have a time series, and need to calculate the maximum y-value. I want this to show up in the plot as a dot.

```
require(reshape2)
require(ggplot2)

# First, prepare the mock data 

t  <- rbind(as.numeric(rnorm(5,1)), as.numeric(rnorm(5,1.1)), as.numeric(rnorm(5,0.9)))
t1 <- apply(t, 1, max)                   # values
t2 <- as.numeric(apply(t, 1, which.max)) # time at values
t3 <- as.data.frame(cbind(t1, t2, c("A","B","C"))) 
colnames(t3) <- c("value","time","variable")

# t3 now containts important calculated points: 
# an (x,y) coordinate for each corresponding variable

t4 <- cbind(t(t), seq(1:5))
colnames(t4) <- c("A","B","C","time")
t4 <- as.data.frame(t4)
t4 <- melt(t4,id.vars="time")

# t4 is the raw data in long format
```

So again, `t4` is my original time series data, and `t3` contains x-y coordinates for each variable.

Plotting each individually seems to work correctly

```
ggplot(t4, aes(x=time,y=value,color=variable))+geom_line()  # points of interest

ggplot(t3, aes(x=time,y=value,color=variable))+geom_point() # all points
```

Simply doing this last time, I was able to graph both dataframes, now it doesn't seem to work.

```
ggplot(t4, aes(x=time,y=value,color=variable))+geom_line() +
  geom_point(data=t3)

Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
```

I'm not quite sure how to format the data correctly to get this to work.

Comment: look at the structure of `t3`, then change it to `t3 <- data.frame(value=t1, time=t2, variable=c("A","B","C"))`

Comment: Thanks BW. This solution has worked in both this example and using my actual data. So my error was using `cbind()` instead of .. I'm having trouble describing the problem

Comment: `cbind` returns a matrix which can only hold one data type - hence everything gets changed to a factor - if all of your values were numeric you wouldn't have noticed an issue. my (probably wrong) understanding of `data.frame()` is that it is for constructing data.frames whereas `as.data.frame()` checks to see if something is a data.frame and coerces it into one if possible.

Comment: not a bad explanation, i'll definitely remember it next time. thanks again